# Flutter: Is there any way to change the row line color of DataTable?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart, datatable, flutter-layout

I'm using `DataTable` in my recent app and i need to change the color of the row line or make it invisible (i mean I don't want to my table shows any row line)

If anyone knows please help! thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [Theme](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Theme-class.html) widget and overriding the [dividerColor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/dividerColor.html) as shown below.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyHomePageState();
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Theme(
          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
              dividerColor: Colors.green
          ),
          child: DataTable(
              columns: [
                DataColumn(label: Text('Language')),
                DataColumn(label: Text('Year'))
              ],
              rows: [
                DataRow(
                  cells: [
                    DataCell(Text('Go')),
                    DataCell(Text('2009'))
                  ],
                ),
                DataRow(
                  cells: [
                    DataCell(Text('Dart')),
                    DataCell(Text('2018'))
                  ],
                ),
                DataRow(
                  cells: [
                    DataCell(Text('Java')),
                    DataCell(Text('1992'))
                  ],
                ),
              ]
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are still looking for the answer, here is the code

```
 return DataRow.byIndex(
          index: row.key,
          color: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
            (states) {
              if (row.key % 2 == 0) {
                return Colors.blue[50];
              } else {
                return Colors.white;
              }
            },
          ),
```

Comment: Make sure you are using list.asMap().entries.map((data)=>//Your work);

Comment: Can You please explain a little more? I am trying to put colors in alternate rows but I am not using constructors. I have about 50 rows. Do I have to manually add color in each row or is there a way to automate this?

Comment: Then how you are displaying data??

Answer (score 1):

Another simple way to generate the divider color is to use horizontalInside of border properties of Datatable:

```
 DataTable(
      border: const TableBorder(
           horizontalInside: BorderSide(
              width: 1,
              color: Colors.green,
           ),
           columns: [],
           rows: [],                                   
     ),
 )
```