# What is the default line style of a Flutter DataTable?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to determine the default line style in a flutter data table

[image]

Looking at the source code is beyond my grasp -

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/data_table.dart

I thought it might be `Border(bottom: new BorderSide(width:1.0, color:Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3)))` but that's just eyeballing it imprecisely.

Comment: Have you tried to follow this? Maybe will help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58658880/flutter-is-there-any-way-to-change-the-row-line-color-of-datatable

Comment: Great - this helps me that it uses DividerColor, I'll still need to find the default the same way.  I'll dig into that widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final BorderSide borderSide = Divider.createBorderSide(
  context,
  width: dividerThickness
      ?? theme.dataTableTheme.dividerThickness
      ?? _dividerThickness,
);
final Border? border = showBottomBorder
    ? Border(bottom: borderSide)
    : index == 0 ? null : Border(top: borderSide);
```

According to [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/da5a454d5c2d39df292948210c83a18d528b5a42/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/data_table.dart#L899)

Comment: Apologies for prodding, but can you lead me to these default theme values for dividerThickness? Which specific gray comes with it?

Comment: This is material default `ThemeData` properties. You can override it with `dataTableTheme: DataTableThemeData(//...)`

Comment: I don't want to override at this time, I just want to know what it is now.  Overriding it would actually be a simpler problem.  Maybe the flutter inspector will tell me.  How can I draw this exact same bottom border is another rephrasing.

Comment: I just need to find the defaults for this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DividerThemeData/DividerThemeData.html

Comment: You have the proper explanation here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/da5a454d5c2d39df292948210c83a18d528b5a42/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/data_table.dart#L497

Comment: I understand the explanation and how the values come to be set (I think), but I'm simply looking for the specific grey and the specific width used in the default themes that makes it way to the DataTable.   Thanks again.

Comment: Here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/da5a454d5c2d39df292948210c83a18d528b5a42/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/divider.dart#L180 and here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/da5a454d5c2d39df292948210c83a18d528b5a42/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart#L332